# Inject a class object in another class without adding it in the constructor

Tags: java, dependency-injection, constructor, guice, lombok

I have a Handler class in which I am using lombok to inject the dependencies and create the required args constructor. The class looks like below:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Inject))
class Handler {
  private final @NonNull ObjectMapper objectMapper;
  private final @NonNull UserAddressBookDao userAddressBookDao;

  //Some methods below
}
```

Now I have to include/inject another class i.e Controller class object in the handler class so the updated handler class would be:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Inject))
class Handler {
  private final @NonNull Mapper mapper;
  private final @NonNull UserDao userDao;
  //newly added class member
  private final @NonNull Controller controller;

  //Some methods below ...'
}
```

I don't want the new class member in the constructor since I have used handler class at a lot of places in my service that If I add a new class member I would have to update code at all those places to add the new member into the constructor. I want the new member to be excluded from the Handler class's constructor so that I can avoid this situation. Also the controller class has a lot of members since initializing it will be a problem if I would try to at the required places. So, is there anyway I can inject Controller into my handler class without including that in the constructor. Thank you so much in advance and please forgive if the question sounds too vague. 
The controller class looks like this:

```
@Singleton
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Inject))
public class Controller {

    @NonNull
    private final ABCService abcClient;
    @NonNull
    private final DdbDao DdbDao;
    @NonNull
    private final ServiceAccessor serviceAccessor;

    `Some methods below ...`
```

Comment: Hi, you want to inject the controller object inside the `Handler` class, right? The controller class has a `@RestController` annotation?

Comment: Hi yes i do but the controller class doesn’t have @RestController annotation. Its just the name Controller  given to the class.

Comment: Can you add also the code of the controller, please? In a Spring application a controller should have that annotation if it exposes apis :)

Comment: I just added that. Its not essentially spring. We used Lombok for the annotations.

Comment: Do you want to expose apis with it?

Comment: Not really, the handler class is a pubsub queue handler that listens to the message after any is published to the queue and the controller is basically a class that was given the message details and applies the business logic on that. No real apis to be exposed here.

Answer (score 0):

- Firstly you have to remove `@NotNull` annotation and `final` modifier from `Controller` field, as **lombok** will pick it up for `@RequiredArgsConstructor`.
   `final` should be removed anyway, as compiler requires it to be assigned by the constructor and you specifically **don't want to set it in a constructor**.
   If you want to keep `@NotNull` then look and **lombok**'s `@SomeArgsConstructor` where you define explicitly which arguments will be set by the constructor.
- then add `@Inject` annotation to the setter for **controller:**
  `@Inject public void setController(Controller controller) {this.controller = controller;}`
  ... so it can be inhjected by guice outside of the constructor.

Comment: I am not using Spring, using Lombok annotations and google guice for the dependency injections.

Comment: you have **spring** not **guice** as a tag under your question... let me fix that

Comment: Lombok doesn't have @SomeArgsConstructor yet and regarding the workaround with method Injection, I am trying the same but the controller is coming as null.